# Is it bad to use the += operator on delegates?

Tags: c#

I just realized I don't know any C#.

Is there any difference between using `+=` and `Delegate.Combine` on delegate instances?

For e.g.

```
public delegate void Printer(string s);

public class Program
{
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    Printer printer = new Printer((s) => { Console.WriteLine(s); });

    // is it wrong to use this += operator 
    // on the delegate instance printer?
    printer += s => {};

    // And is this somewhat holier than the previous one?
    // why?
    Delegate.Combine(printer, new Printer((s) => {});
  }
}
```

I ask this question because it seemed to be implied by *serge karalenka's* answer on this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15183049/303685

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14197857/composing-multicast-delegates-in-c-sharp-shoud-i-use-operators-or-action-combi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it bad? No, not at all. In fact, I prefer it.

One good reason to use it instead of `Combine()` is that one is less likely to make the mistake you made in your example: failing to actually assign the result to something. I.e. note that the `Combine()` method returns the new delegate instance. Like `string`, delegates are immutable and all modifications involve creating a new instance.

While it is possible to make the same mistake with the `+` operator, most people would not write the code as `printer + (s => {})` and even if they did, it would be pretty obvious in that case that the result of the expression was not assigned to anything. The more idiomatic `+=` is of course immune to the problem completely. :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `+=` is perfectly fine.  The language wouldn't have a bunch of special rules to make it work properly on delegates, if it was a bad thing.

It also has the advantage of working, while the second one doesn't.